# SQL server error- "Database 10 cannot be autostarted during server shutdown or startup."

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create new database but SQL server throwing error like : **"Database 10 cannot be autostarted during server shutdown or startup."**

[image]

Thanks in advance for your reply

Comment: It's rather obvious something is happening with the server (It's either still booting up, or it's getting ready to reboot). You'l have to wait for that to complete.

Comment: I have create new server instance for now. But issue is something regarding privileges. Actually I executed one database script after that this was happening. Still I'm trying to find what is the issue. :)